# Partial view appearing as a plain view without layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I am facing an issue here with the partial views. I created a partial view with the option for "Use a layout" as checked so that it could accept it. But when I run my code, the partial view appears without layout. It just appears in a new white window with just controls on it, no styling, no JQuery etc.

This is my controller code :

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ShowVersion(Model obj)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
               //some logic here...
               if (check)
                    {
                        if (currentVersion == 0) 
                            return PartialView("_Feedback",otaNew);
                    }
            }
        }
```

I tried `ViewResult` instead of `ActionResult` but that didnt help. Also tried to use `return View()` but no progress.

Need some help on this.

Thanks.

Comment: if we return partialview from controller action then in mvc no layout will be associated with partial view...because partial view is used to display inside main view and main view has its own layout.

Comment: **i am not sure**...but if you want layout inside partial view also then write this code at the top of partial view `@{
Layout = "path of layout";
}`

Comment: @Kartikeya - I tried that. So what it does now is that it displays the partial view as a whole new view but not as a pop like I want. The styling appears when doing this.

Comment: its definitely problem with building view(partial inside layout) not from controller end . let me try if i can give some example on this .

Comment: i believe you have to do something like this build main view & partial as seperate view . later on you need to use `render partial` helper method . follow this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/698246/ASP-NET-MVC-Special-Views-Partial-View-and-Layout .

Answer (score 0):

just set some value `currentVersion = 0` in your model and return model to view and on view you can check .

```
 if( Model.currentVersion == 0 )
    {  
      @Html.Partial("_Feedback",otaNew)
    }
```